# simple mailto function that composing an email from html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email, mailto

I need to create a simple mailto function so when I click on the html file it brings up my default email application with the composed mail "ready-to-go."  I figured a click event on the mailto ID would be sufficient, but it is not firing.  What should I do?  FYI, I do not want the user to click on the hyperlink.  I plan on removing it.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mymailto").click();
 }); // document.ready

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <TITLE>Your Title Here</TITLE>
 <META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <META http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
 <META http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
 <META http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
 <a href="mailto:testEmail@gmail.com" id="mymailto" >email</a>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `document.location.href="mailto:testEmail@gmail.com";`.

Comment: Cool.  Is there anyway to add the style="display:none" to this?

Comment: What you mean "add the `style="display:none"` to this"? Because it should replace your `$("#mymailto").click();`. No html tag is required.